# mergedGeometry LineSegment combination problem Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I want to create my edge lines of merged geometry. But with that code ı can create edges lines independentyl with 2  main geometry

```js
// Combine two geometries
const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.01, 9.1, 0.01);
const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const mergedGeometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(
  [geometry1, geometry2]
);

// Create a mesh with a material that suppresses edge lines
const mergedMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x542452,
    wireframe: true,  // Enable wireframe rendering
    opacity: 0,       // Set opacity to 0 to suppress edge lines
    transparent: true // Make the material transparent
});

const mergedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, mergedMaterial);
scene.add(mergedMesh);

// Create edges for the entire merged geometry
const edgesGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(mergedMesh.geometry);
const mergedLines = new THREE.LineSegments(
    edgesGeometry,
    new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
);

scene.add(mergedLines);
```

I want to

Comment: It looks like the end of your question is missing. What happens when you run this code, and what do you hope would happen? Any other errors or screenshots or details you can share?